# How can I write this sum as an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals

Given:
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n/2} \left[\frac1{\epsilon_{g}}\ln\left(\frac{x_{2i-1}}{x_{2i-2}}\right) \,+\, \frac1{\epsilon_{l}}\ln\left(\frac{x_{2i}}{x_{2i-1}}\right)\right]
$$

where $\epsilon_{g}$ and $\epsilon_{l}$ are different constants.

Is it possible to write it as an integral?

Comment: Certainty not without more details on the $x_i$.

Comment: But if you use $\ln(a/b) =\ln(a)-\ln(b)$, and write out the first 3-4 terms to see the pattern, can't you just turn this into the sum of a bunch of $\ln(x_i)$, with different factors in front of the odd and even terms?